# Nativescript - resumeEvent handling

Tags: nativescript

In my app when the app is resumed from a sleep, I'd like to 
reload the page - or ideally, just update specific UI elements.

How can this be done?

Preferably in a platform independent way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to hook into the `onResume` method in the `application` module which exposes the event when an app resumes from the background.

[https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/*application*.html#onresume](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_application_.html#onresume)

So in your `app.js` (the entry point of your application), import the module and add the onResume event handler and it can run everytime the app resumes. Now reloading a page will require a little more work. You'd have to use the `frame` module and find out the current page and do your work, but I'm guessing it can be done with a little effort using the approach mentioned.

**UPDATE:** based off your comment, you need the `reloadPage()` method from the `ui/frame` module. https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_frame_.html#reloadpage

Comment: My apologies for not specifying more. I've got the event callback and also can get current page via frameModule.topmost().currentPage. I was looking for something like refresh(), reload() - didn't find anything.

Comment: that's for iOS - but thanks. Now looking for a solution for Android.

Comment: If it's only for iOS then you should add a PR to the repo stating that. It's part of the core `ui/frame` module and I don't see where you are finding that it's iOS only. Do you have a link?

Comment: My apologies again - got the braces mixed up in the file. But in VS and typescript, reloadPage() is being flagged as undefined. I'll look into this more.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question so I can see what you're trying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135426/discussion-between-dashman-and-brad-martin).

Comment: Sure. I'm heading out, be on later.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is reloadPage() in the Frame module (as contributed by @Brad) but the problem is that it's NOT an exposed api.

No problem - just copy/paste it and it works.

The problem is that it basically does a navigateTo() to the currentPage and that effects the navigation history. You have 2 choices - setting clearHistory to true and you lose all history (don't want that) or set clearHistory to false which creates a a duplicate of the current-page (don't want that either). There's also a backstackVisible option but that doesn't help in this scenario.

@Brad tells me that there's api that allows access to the navigation stack - haven't looked into it.

For my app - the user will be at the root page most of the time, so I decided to reload the page only if on the root page and then set clearHistory to true and that works for me.